# Angular Date converts to locale without adding hours

Tags: angular, date

I am getting **UTC date** from backend that is being loaded by **Angular** and **Angular** automatically adds locale timezone however it does not add hour difference that this zone provides. Eg. I get `2019-12-26 10:00:00.0000000` from backend and I receive it like `Thu Dec 26 2019 10:00:00 GMT+0100` when it should be `Thu Dec 26 2019 11:00:00 GMT+0100`.
When I try `new Date(date)` it does nothing because it already has timezone but with wrong hour.

Comment: What is your code? How is Angular (or whatever you're using to parse that date) supposed to know that this is a a UTC date? Use the standard, ISO format: 2019-12-26T10:00:00Z.

Comment: The time / offset is usuallzy always to GMT+0, therefore the time returned is 10:00 in GMT+0, and gets converted to 11:00 (in GMT+1).  11:00:00 GMT+0100 would convert to 12:00:00

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the locale of your app, in order to stop angular to convert automatically to yours.

You can do that in your app-module.ts file, as specified here : https://angular.io/guide/i18n#setting-up-the-locale-of-your-app

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with moment.js using moment.utc().

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

```
var str = '2011-04-11T10:20:30Z';
var date = moment.utc(str);
```